# Hindley Milner Type Inference in F#

Tags: f#, type-inference, hindley-milner

Can somebody explain step by step type inference in following F# program:

```
let rec sumList lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> 0
    | hd :: tl -> hd + sumList tl
```

I specifically want to see step by step how process of unification in Hindley Milner works.

Comment: I think this might belong in another SE site, but not sure which :)

Comment: If it is can you give me a link to that? It would be helpful.

Comment: Well, I'd think it belongs to Theo CS, but I don't think they'd welcome it. Unless a smart moderator comes along, I guess this'll just remain here :)

Comment: I did not get it. Could you find that link?

Comment: This isn't exactly a technical question about programming, so it might not fit StackOverflow. I had suggested this site: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not sure it'll fit there, too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fun stuff!

First we invent a generic type for sumList:
`x -> y`

And get the simple equations:
`t(lst) = x`;
`t(match ...) = y`

Now you add the equation:
`t(lst) = [a]` because of `(match lst with [] ...)`

Then the equation:
`b = t(0) = Int`; `y = b`

Since 0 is a possible result of the match:
`c = t(match lst with ...) = b`

From the second pattern:
`t(lst) = [d]`;
`t(hd) = e`;
`t(tl) = f`;
`f = [e]`;
`t(lst) = t(tl)`;
`t(lst) = [t(hd)]`

Guess a type (a generic type) for `hd`:
`g = t(hd)`; `e = g`

Then we need a type for `sumList`, so we'll just get a meaningless function type for now:
`h -> i = t(sumList)`

So now we know:
`h = f`;
`t(sumList tl) = i`

Then from the addition we get:
`Addable g`;
`Addable i`;
`g = i`;
`t(hd + sumList tl) = g`

Now we can start unification:

`t(lst) = t(tl)` `=>` `[a] = f = [e]` `=>` `a = e`

`t(lst) = x = [a] = f = [e]`; `h = t(tl) = x`

`t(hd) = g = i` `/\` `i = y` `=>` `y = t(hd)`

`x = t(lst) = [t(hd)]` `/\` `t(hd) = y` `=>` `x = [y]`

`y = b = Int` `/\` `x = [y]` `=>` `x = [Int]` `=>` `t(sumList) = [Int] -> Int`

I skipped some trivial steps, but I think you can get how it works.

Comment: Thanks :) had to read each line twice-thrice but now understood it. Thanks again.